# Android 10 hotspot WPA2 enable AES or PSK

Tags: windows-10, android, wpa2

Well, everything was working fine until now that when I enabled my Hotspot on Windows 10 it says it's not secure which from what I found out is that it's not using AES/PSK but it's a WPA2-Personal so was wondering if there is a way to add or enable those options for hotspot

[image]

Here is some information:

Xiaomi Redmi 8 (rooted) (Android 10)

Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.746

Comment: WPA-Personal and WPA-PSK is the same thing

Comment: @gronostaj oh then why Windows giving a warning that my hotspot isn't secure but when I check my AP is WPA2-Personal I checked with inSSIDer

Comment: I don't know - you haven't shown us even the exact error message, not to mention more results of your investigation.

Comment: @gronostaj Well there isn't much I just added the message that Windows shows me it's pretty much just that